# Ajax post call in admin-ajax.php returns 0 with 400 bad request (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Hi as you can see I'm trying to send my data to admin-ajax.php using ajax post call kindly check the code below and the template that I use is betheme.

index.html

```
        $('#send-form').on('submit', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data : {
                    'action' : 'test_func',
                    'data':'lorem ipsum'
                },
                type : 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function (callback) {

                    console.log(callback);
                }
            });

            return false;

        });
```

functions.php

```
function test_func () {
    echo json_encode(array('res'=>'return dummy text'));
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_func', 'test_func');
```

Comment: Use **wp_send_json()** instead of the **echo** - that’s the “WP way” https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json

Comment: Hey @muka.gergely nice info cheers

Answer (score 1):

As per the code of ajax no need of adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8` because you are passing data as string, so `contentType` property is not required.

To fix the issue of getting `0` every time you just have to add `wp_die()` at the end of `test_func` method.

Here you edited code

1) jQuery Ajax Code:

```
jQuery('#send-form').on('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            data : {
                'action' : 'test_func',
                'data':'lorem ipsum'
            },
            type : 'POST',
            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (callback) {

                console.log(callback);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

2) Code of `functions.php`

```
function test_func () {
    echo json_encode(array('res'=>'return dummy text'));
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_func', 'test_func'); // ajax call for non-login user.
add_action('wp_ajax_test_func', 'test_func'); // ajax call for login user.
```

Comment: Hey Sohil I already fixed the issue but still your right about removing contentType in ajax and about the wp_die() is it just the same as die() or exit()?

Comment: contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default.You can write die() or exit() instead of wp_die() it will work. But if you are working on wordpress ajax then wp_die() is a inbuilt method provided.It is just as wordpress way to write.